# Beginner's question: Inserting Emoji in Java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, emoji

I would like to let a certain emoji be displayed.

Could someone give me an example of any emoji on how this should look like?

I know there is unicode emojis but I don't know the exact syntax that I should use.

Comment: `System.out.println("");`

Comment: how did you make the shit appear my friend?

Comment: i mean, i should use some unicode right? how exactly does it work

Comment: the assignment is i should use unicode

Comment: See https://lemire.me/blog/2018/06/15/emojis-java-and-strings/

Answer (score 3):

A Unicode Emoji is just another Unicode character, however, since Java strings are stored as UTF-16, an Emoji character is actually 2 Java `char` *surrogate pairs*.

If you store your Java source code in UTF-8, you can simply copy/paste Emoji characters from any web site listing Emoji's (e.g. https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) into a Java string literal, like [Elliott Frisch showed you in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026983/beginners-question-inserting-emoji-in-java#comment92955680_53026983).

E.g. here is a copy/paste of the first "Browser" symbol from the link above:

```
String grinningFace = "";
```

If your source files are not stored in UTF-8, you need to write the Unicode escape sequence for the Emoji, and as explained earlier, that actually means two characters.

A web site like [fileformat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm) is useful here, because it shows the Unicode Escape sequence, so the same Emoji as above (['GRINNING FACE' (U+1F600)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm)) is written like this:

```
String grinningFace = "\uD83D\uDE00";
```